# How to get certificate from client Store?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using following code for accessing certificate from client store. Also I changed `impersonate = true` in web.config. The below code woks fine in my local machine but in production it fails and no certificate retrieve. My IIS version is greater than 7.0

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
int count = store.Certificates.Count;
var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, cert.SerialNumber, true);
store.Close();
```

Comment: Where does javascript and jquery figure into this?

Comment: it might be solved in javascript or jquery

Comment: "it fails" - we're going to need a bit more than that, does it fail with an exception? What message do you get? Does it make sense to use the `CurrentUser` store on a server? Please refer to [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance on how to ask a better question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Fails in the seance Certificate count is Zero.Means it is not retrieving Certificate from Client Store.